# How to apply styles to the custom page template

Tags: customization, pages, templates

I have made a simple page template according to what is said in the how to here :[Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#Custom_Page_Template)

When I create a page and in its 'Page attributes' make the template equal to the one I've created, everything is displayed but not in the order specified by the style.css . there is actually no styling applied to my page at all. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share your template code. Perhaps you forgot adding header and/or footer. That's why the stylesheet couldn't enqueued.

Comment: On this site there is very little point to ask a question if you do not add your code to it. Please edit the question and add  all relevant code. Might be even a good idea to give a url  to the page in question.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, the problem is now solved. I had used both the parameters 'loop' and 'page' for the get_template_part function in the custom template's content php code. I removed the 'loop' parameter and ... voila , it works fine now.